# how to manipulate image before display in contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript

I need to manipulate `img` element before inserting it into a `contenteditable` div.

here next is my attempt. to do ..

1. add `EditorImgs` class to the image assign
2. add `src` to that image

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var ImgCmd = document.getElementById('ImgCmd');
    var uploader = document.getElementById('ImageUploader');
    ImgCmd.addEventListener('click', () => uploader.click());
});
var editer = document.getElementById('design_view');
function uploadFile(e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    editer.focus();
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    // console.log(url); // blob:https://localhost:34564/1v9m120z-y982-4np3-a8ah-9uead3dj6743
    var Img = document.createElement('img');
    Img.src = url;
    Img.setAttribute("class", "EditorImgs");
    document.execCommand('insertImage', false, Img);
}
```

```css
.EditorImgs 
{
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: both;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input id="ImageUploader" type="file" hidden="hidden" onchange="uploadFile(event)" />

<button id="ImgCmd">Insert Image</button>

<div contenteditable id="design_view"></div>
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `document.execCommand('insertImage')`, the third argument should be the URL, not an image element.

```
document.execCommand('insertImage', false, url);
```

If you want to style the image, you could use `document.execCommand('insertHTML')` or [`Range#insertNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode).

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
range.insertNode(Img);
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var ImgCmd = document.getElementById('ImgCmd');
    var uploader = document.getElementById('ImageUploader');
    ImgCmd.addEventListener('click', () => uploader.click());
});
var editer = document.getElementById('design_view');
function uploadFile(e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    editer.focus();
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var Img = document.createElement('img');
    Img.src = url;
    Img.setAttribute("class", "EditorImgs");
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
    range.insertNode(Img);
}
```

```css
.EditorImgs 
{
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: both;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input id="ImageUploader" type="file" hidden="hidden" onchange="uploadFile(event)" />

<button id="ImgCmd">Insert Image</button>

<div contenteditable id="design_view"></div>
```